# Getting the current status of a FlipView object

Tags: interface

```
Clear["Global`*"];
Table[FlipView[Framed[Style["A", 32, Black, Bold]
     , ImageSize -> {60, 60}, Alignment -> Center, 
     Background -> #] & /@ Lighter@{Red, Green, Blue}, 1], {4}]
```

[image]

**Question**

As the colors change upon clicking, I would like to get the colors (or indices of the colors) for the four items as a list. How can this be done?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`FlipView`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FlipView.html) allows the second argument to be `Dynamic`.

```
k = Table[1, {4}];
Table[With[{i = i}, 
  FlipView[
   Framed[Style["A", 32, Black, Bold], ImageSize -> {60, 60}, 
      Alignment -> Center, Background -> #] & /@ 
    Lighter@{Red, Green, Blue}, Dynamic[k[[i]]]]], {i, 4}]

Dynamic@k
(* {1, 1, 1, 1} *)
```